# Possible to skip website web.config in sub application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In IIS I want to deploy a sub application in a website. I really don't want to bother with having to update the root website's web.config with location tags all over the place.

Is it possible to direct the sub application to just totally ignore the root website's web.config?

---

Okay, so that's my question. The following is just additional information that could lead someone to offer an alternate solution I haven't thought of but if possible I hope you won't judge my post on the following since, as I mentioned, the above is my question... this is just extra information for the interested:

I am deploying several websites. Each website will have an admin application which will have the same codebase. I want the admin application to be available at site1.com/admin, site2.com/admin, etc.

In the past I did something similar on another project, but instead of having sub apps I did sub domains to another site... so it would have been like site1.admin.com, site2.admin.com, etc. Nice thing about this solution was the ease of just adding additional bindings for any new site (and the application would look at host name to apply proper theming, configuration, security, etc.). I would have preferred this solution again but it just won't work this time because we can't easily secure a proper domain name for that purpose and aside from that we would prefer the user stay on the same domain name anyway just from a marketing perspective.

So ultimately my goals are:

- Have the web address be "sitename.com/admin"
- Only deploy the admin application to one location
- Avoid spending 2 days trying to figure out how to properly configure everything so that configs don't clash and then still end up with a
  few errors I spontaneously find over the course of the next week and
  eventually find one that requires me to reprogram a large section of
  code in order to play nicely with the root website. (If you can't
  tell, I may have minor PTSD from trying something like this a couple
  years back).

I mean, what would be really super is if I could have admin be its own web application and have bindings like "site1.com/admin" and "site2.com/admin" but obviously that's not possible. But maybe there are some other straightforward solutions I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: You could use <location inheritInChildApplications="false">
     <NotInheritedConfigPart/>
</location> in your web.config file to do not inherited by child applications.[link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/How-to-prevent-web-config-files-to-be-overwritten-by-config/ba-p/297627)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Yeah I can do that but, as I alluded to in my post, I had some issues with a similar implementation I tried that way before. And it's easy to cause unintended side effects when you update the root web.config in the future. I was hoping for for a solution where I can basically have a completely separate application that is not really a subapp from a functional standpoint, but that could be configured to be accessed as though it were in regard to the web address.

Comment: Could you tell us what is your actual requirement." had some issues with a similar implementation I tried that way before." which kind of issue you are talking about?